# How to get the difference between two datetime objects in ThingsDB?

Tags: datetime, thingsdb

I'm using two datetime objects. Is it possible to get the difference between those two?

For example:

```
a = datetime('2023-03-30 12:00:00');
b = datetime('2023-03-30 15:10:30');

// I would like to calculate "b - a" but this raises a type error:
//  `-` not supported between `datetime` and `datetime`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the datetime objects to integer first. This will return the Unix timestamp for the given datetime objects.
With the Unix timestamps it is easy to get the difference.

```
diff = int(b) - int(a);   // 11430 seconds with the values from your example
```